# Sublime Text 2 - New tab keyboard shortcut?

Tags: sublimetext2

What is the keyboard shortcut to create a new file in a new tab for Sublime Text?

I am running Sublime Text 2 on OSX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ctrl+N. This is the combination for windows, not entirely sure if it's the same for other OS.

Answer (score -2):

Here you have a nice summary of the most used shorcuts in Sublime Text:

http://scotch.io/bar-talk/sublime-text-keyboard-shortcuts

Have fun ;)